# Surface mount electrical box

Tags: electrical, brick, junction-box

Had a box with outlet inside cabinet. The cabinet has been removed, however I still want to have an outlet. My problems:

1. I can’t recess a box into the wall, because there’s an old brick fireplace 1” in.
2. It will be showing, so I don’t want a blue box on surface of the wall.

[image]

What type of box would you recommend using?

Comment: Hopefully the picture i posted is showing 

Comment: Why do you think you can't recess into brick? Every socket & light switch in my house is recessed into brick.

Comment: Why would I want to try to cut out a huge piece of brick 3 or 5 inches deep plus s channel for the wiring running from the attic down to the box when   it could be surface mounted instead?

Comment: ermm… because it's so much neater, surface boxes are an ugly last resort, usually only for cellars & garages; the cable's already there, no need to channel it. Recessed boxes here are between ½" & 1½" depending on how much space you need. Not sure about US boxes, but I'd imagine similar.

Comment: Nope- they’re about 4”. Besides its going to be behind a refrigerator not will look fine ☺️

Answer (score 6):

Your description is good, search those words. There are plastic and metal boxes designed for surface raceways. But, as long as it has a knock-out in the back, you can use it alone.

[image]

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-1-Gang-1-89-in-Box-Depth-Surface-Mount-Back-Box-White-42777-1WA/302070550

Comment: Thats the exact one I purchased but in reading more it says for low voltage only. That’s what made me confused enough to think I should write on here and ask lol

Comment: The one answer in the Q&A section is wrong IMO. Here is a metal one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-700-Series-Metal-Surface-Raceway-Extra-Deep-Electrical-Box-White-BW35/202264869

Comment: Since dont have a raceway coming into it would I just knockout the circular plug on the back and pull wires through that? Also the metal box itself has a grounding screw as does the outlet that comes with the box. Instructions dont say what to do with each of these. Im familiar with the one on the outlet itself but what do i do with the one on the metal box itself? Thanks

Comment: Metal boxes must be grounded. And you should add a clamp at the cable entrance hole.

Comment: Ugh getting complicated. I just took it out of the cabinet so could remove the cabinet, thought ot would be simple just to hook up again on The wall so can plug refrigerator into it. But I have no idea about grounding the box itself or buying a clamp that would fit this box.

Answer (score 4):

While product recommendations are OT here, Wiremold makes fairly attractive shallow boxes that might meet your needs.

[image: shallow outlet box]

Comment: Thank you. I had bought one that looked similar but afterwards I realized it was for low voltage only. I’ll take a look at the one you mentioned!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome! From what I can see you will have to do some drywall repair anyway so let's use that to you advantage. I believe there is a stud between the two wires hence the kluge. I would recommend putting a rework box slightly above where the upper wire comes through the drywall and mounting it to the stu on the left, be sure you will have enough wire. While you have the hole there  Drill a hole through the stud and then fish the other wire up. Place them both in the same box and connect them. You can put a duplex on it or just a blank plate either will work. In the end it will look professional. This would probably be the most economical solution.

Comment: You misunderstood. The sheetrock is glued directly  onto an old brick fireplace, there is NO space for a recessed old work box and NO Studs. Thats why I need a surface mount. That will cover the hole in the sheetrock where the wire is poking through as well so really not sheetrock work to do. But thanks!